# how to write to a single file in multi threading concept of spring batch

Tags: spring-batch

I am reading from a database and writing to a file for that scenario I am using multi threading concept. In a flow I declared 4 steps and those 4 steps are working parellelly but in this scenario I can able to write the result to 4 different csv files.

My requirement is to write the 4 threads data to a single file. If I give same file name in 4 places will it work or it overrides the data. please suggest me.

Comment: What keeps you from writing into a single file without multi-threading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write 4 different files and create an extra step to concatenate previously created pieces in one big file (a [SystemCommandTasklet](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/step/tasklet/SystemCommandTasklet.html) might fit)